# I am getting the Error: Expected ',' before this. in my code specifying the body in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, error-handling

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar:AppBar(
        title: Text('New project',style: TextStyle(fontSize:25,color: Colors.green,decorationStyle: TextDecorationStyle.dotted ),),
    )
        body: Center(
         child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
          Text('How many times pushed'),
          Text('ok')
      ],
    ),
    ),

    );

  }
}
```

When I try to run the code,I am getting the error "Expected ',' before this" close to the body, Whats the soltuion for it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code add `,` before body start

```
return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(
          'New project',
          style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 25,
              color: Colors.green,
              decorationStyle: TextDecorationStyle.dotted),
        ),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[Text('How many times pushed'), Text('ok')],
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Result-> [image]

Comment: @NipunaThalpage please try to accept my answer if its help to you

Answer (score 0):

```
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text(
      'New project',
      style: TextStyle(
          fontSize: 25,
          color: Colors.green,
          decorationStyle: TextDecorationStyle.dotted),
    ),
  ), -----------------> add , here
  body: Center(
    child: Column(
      children: <Widget>[Text('How many times pushed'), Text('ok')],
    ),
  ),
);
```